# C# to VB.NET: Inheritance and interfaces

Tags: c#, vb.net, inheritance, interface

I have the following class in C#:

```
public class SyncListener : SyncStatusListener
{ ... }
```

and I want to convert it to VB.NET which I think would look like this:

```
Public Class SyncListener
    Inherits SyncStatusListener
    ...
End Class
```

but here comes the question: `SyncStatusListener` is an interface and VB.NET does not allow inherit from interfaces. How can I convert the C# code to VB.NET in this case?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [`Implements` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4b3c4by9%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) instead.

> If a class or structure implements one or more interfaces, it must include the **Implements** statement immediately after the **Class** or **Structure** statement. The **Implements** statement requires a comma-separated list of interfaces to be implemented by a class. The class or structure must implement all interface members using the **Implements** keyword.

So change your code to:

```
Public Class SyncListener
    Implements SyncStatusListener
    ...
End Class
```

Comment: It might be helpful to elaborate on your last sentence, showing the equivalents of implicit and explicit interface implementations.

Answer (score 1):

For VB.Net you use the implements keyword, not inherits.  See here. [Implements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/28e2e18x.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Use **[Implements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/28e2e18x.aspx)**

```
Public Class SyncListener
    Implements SyncStatusListener
    ...
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

In C# for `Interface` implementation is done by a `:`. But `VB.Net` have reserved a keyword for this.

Keyword for Interface implementation is `Implements`

You can implement multiple `Interface` in two ways.

One is Use `Implements` keyword for each `Interface`

```
Public Class Test
     Implements Interface1
     Implements Interface2

End Class
```

another one method is to use a comma -seperater like below

```
Public Class Test
    Implements Interface1, Interface2

End Class
```